# How to group different data of same date on json file with flutter?

Tags: flutter

I successed to convert a list of all key/value saved with sharedpreference and convert only the data I need in a json format to display a list of data I want to show.

Problem: I use regex, and I group each key/value/date in this format

```
[{"dateTime":"2020-10-30","note3":"test1"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-29","note3":"test2"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-31","note3":"test3"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-29","note4":"test4"}]
```

Currently I display each data in listview

like that

```
card1
2020-10-30
note3 = test1

card2
2020-10-29
note3 = test2

card3
2020-10-31
note3 = test3

card4
2020-10-29
note4 = test4
```

I search to data for each same date like that

```
card1
2020-10-30
note3 = test1

card2
2020-10-29
note3 = test2  note4 = test4


card3
2020-10-31
note3 = test3
```

As Card4 had the same date Card2 I want display  two data in same card

to do this I need to group my json file like that

```
input
[{"dateTime":"2020-10-30","note3":"test1"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-29","note3":"test2"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-31","note3":"test3"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-29","note4":"test4"}]


output
[{"dateTime":"2020-10-30","note3":"test1"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-29","note3":"test2","note4":"test4"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-31","note3":"test3"},
```

Currently if I write manually this output it display like I want, but I don't found out to convert input to output

thank you

Comment: use [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html)

Comment: I just try but not the output expected to be compatible with my code. I have this output =>  {10/01/2019: [{release_date: 10/01/2019, note3: test1}], 30/10/2019: [{release_date: 30/10/2019, note3: test2}, {release_date: 30/10/2019, note3: test3}]}.  I search to have this =>  [{"dateTime":"2020-10-30","note3":"test1"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-29","note3":"test2","note4":"test4"}, {"dateTime":"2020-10-31","note3":"test3"},

Comment: you can modify the returned `Map`, for example: `var foo = [
{'id': 0, 'name': 'foo'},
{'id': 1, 'name': 'spam'},
{'id': 0, 'name': 'bar'},
];
var foo2 = groupBy(foo, (i) => i['id']);
print('foo2: $foo2');
var foo3 = foo2.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.map((e) => e['name'])));
print('foo3: $foo3');
`

Comment: I have some trouble with this, first with this example I have in output {0: (foo, bar), 1: (spam)} and my code don't recognize this. I search to have {"date":"0": "foo":"bar", "date":"1": "spam"}. other problem my input isn't a String but a ListString and I can't replace foo by my variable. I tried to add .toString() but itsn't accepted.